# Flutter debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false not remove debug banner

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to remove the debug banner from my application and I added `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` in my main.dart and every activity but still showing the debug banner.

Main.dart

```
void main() async {

  runApp(MaterialApp(home:SplashScreen(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,));

}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
 

  startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 1);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        new CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomesApp()));

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: colorGreen),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Center(
              child: new Image.asset('assets/green_h_logo.png',color: Colors.white,height: 150,width: 150,)
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
                height: 50,
                child:new Image.asset('assets/h.gif')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above code is my main.dart, it loads a splash screen and after a second it navigates to myhomesapp which has bottomnavigationbar as below:

home.dart

```
class MyHomesApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      title: 'App Name',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        fontFamily: "Montserrat", //my custom font
      ),
      builder: (context, child) {

        return ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: MyBehavior(),
          child: child,
        );
      },

      home: Homes(),

    );
  }
}


class Homes extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Homes> {
  int _currentIndex;
  List<Widget> _children;



  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentIndex = 0;
    _children = [
      MyDealApp(),
      MyRedemptionApp(),
      MyProfileApp()
    ];

    _loadCounter();


    super.initState();
  }

  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      myInt = prefs.getInt('id') ?? 0;
      _email = (prefs.getString('email') ?? '');
      _fullname = (prefs.getString('fullname') ?? '');
      currentTabs = prefs.getInt('currentTab') ?? 0;
      debugPrint("currentTabMain:$currentTabMain");
      debugPrint("emailr:$_email");

    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    const assetHome = 'assets/home_off.svg';
    const assetRedemptions = 'assets/redeemed_off.svg';
    const assetCommunity = 'assets/community_off.svg';
    const assetProfile = 'assets/profile_off.svg';


    const assetHome1 = 'assets/home_on.svg';
    const assetRedemptions1 = 'assets/redeemed_on.svg';
    const assetCommunity1 = 'assets/community_on.svg';
    const assetProfile1 = 'assets/profile_on.svg';


    return Container(

      height: 30,

        child:CupertinoTabScaffold(

        tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          backgroundColor: colorGreen,

          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _currentIndex == 0 ?SvgPicture.asset(assetHome1,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  semanticsLabel: 'Home'):SvgPicture.asset(assetHome,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  semanticsLabel: 'Home'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon:  _currentIndex == 1 ?SvgPicture.asset(assetRedemptions1,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  semanticsLabel: 'Redemptions'):SvgPicture.asset(assetRedemptions,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  semanticsLabel: 'Redemptions'),

            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem( icon:  _currentIndex == 2 ? SvgPicture.asset(assetProfile1,
                color: Colors.white,
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                semanticsLabel: 'Profile'):SvgPicture.asset(assetProfile,
                color: Colors.white,
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                semanticsLabel: 'Profile'),

             ),
          ],

        ),
        tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SafeArea(
                top: false,
                bottom: false,
                child: CupertinoApp(
                  home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                    child: _children[_currentIndex],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
    ));
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
      debugPrint("tabbottom:$_currentIndex");

    });
  }
}
```

I used the same for  `MyRedemptionApp()` and `MyProfileApp()` respectively. The major issue is `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` is not removing the debug banner because the debug banner shows on every page. How to remove the debug banner?

Comment: I think you have two `MaterialApp` widget. Please use one `MaterialApp`. for one app

Comment: Am using materialapp to stop materialization error which requires materialapp at the root of the application

Answer (score 9):

This normally happens when you have multiple MaterialApp widgets used. If you don't think you can reduce to one just use debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false whenever you use MaterialApp widgets throughout your application.